# Returning a scanner, specifically a File

Tags: java, return, try-catch, ioexception

So I want

```
public static Scanner fileWriter()
{
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("What is the name of the file? (succeeded by .txt)");
  //String firs = sc.nextLine();
  try
  {
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("Test.txt"));
  }
  catch(IOException e)
  {
   System.out.println("Io exception" + e.getMessage());
  }
  return scanner;  
 }
```

While this works, the only thing I am having issues with is the 'return scanner'.

The error is "cannot find symbol"

```
return scanner;
       ^
```

What am I doing wrong? :( Thanks!

Comment: Variables have *scope*. Specifically, to the enclosing block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("Test.txt"));
```

is inside the curly braces of the `try` block.  Therefore, it is visible only within those curly braces.  To make sure it's visible outside, **declare** the variable before the `try`:

```
Scanner scanner;
```

and then, inside the `try` block, just assign to it, don't declare it (the difference is that you don't include the type name; that makes it an assignment statement):

```
scanner = new Scanner(new File("Test.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`scanner` isn't visible outside the scope of the try block. You could do the following instead:

```
public static Scanner fileWriter()
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the name of the file? (succeeded by .txt)");
    String fileName = sc.nextLine();
    try
    {
        return new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Io exception" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```